# Writing custom DependencyResolver using Unity IoC DI Container

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have a class, `A`, which takes one argument, `HttpSessionStateBase`, in its constructor.

In another class, `B`, which implements an interface `InterfaceB`, will use the `A` to construct itself.

How do I write the code so that I can have the `B` injected in my Controller?

Currently, here is the AddBinding method which does the DI register stuff:

```
public void AddBinding()
{
     container.RegisterType<IService1, Service1Impl>();
     container.RegisterType<IService2, Service2Impl>();      
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both A (Service1Impl), B (Service2Impl) and is registerd within your continer and your controller using that container for inversion of control, B will be resolved.

Your unity registration can look like this, using an InjectionFactory:

```
container.RegisterType<HttpSessionStateBase>(
new InjectionFactory(x => new HttpSessionStateWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session)));
container.RegisterType<IService1, Service1Impl>();
container.RegisterType<IService2, Service2Impl>();
```

I have tested this with classes/interfaces looking like this:

```
public interface IService1 { }

public interface IService2 { }

public class Service1Impl : IService1 
{
    public Service1Impl(HttpSessionStateBase ctx)
    {

    }

}

public class Service2Impl : IService2
{
    public Service2Impl(IService1 service1)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: But I dont want to explicitly call the static HttpContext class in my class. I want it to be injected in my code. Any idea and comments?

Comment: Ok, I edit that answer a bit. Does that anser your question ?